# Increment counter in nested v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a nested data structure like so:

```
allItems: [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
]
```

that I need to represent exactly like this:

```
Category 1
..........(a) Item 1
..........(b) Item 2
..........(c) Item 3
Category 2
..........(d) Item 4
..........(e) Item 5
..........(f) Item 6
Category 3
..........(g) Item 7
..........(h) Item 8
..........(i) Item 9
```

But I am not able to keep a counter in between v-for...
Note that I have no control over the data and user will be offered to sort data however he wants making it impossible for me to add a counter within the data.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4je123th/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/de0ktf23/

Comment: @bcjohn thanks ! This is the correct answer for me as it is simpler than the one suggested. If you submit a proper answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```html
<template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(row,i) in allItems" :key="row">
    Category {{i+1}}
    {{ updateCnt(row, i) }}

    <div v-for="(col,j) in row" :key="col">
...................({{col}}) Item {{ cnt + j + 1}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    allItems: [
      ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      ['d', 'e', 'f'],
      ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    ], 
    cnt: 0
  },
  methods: {
    updateCnt(row, i) {
      this.cnt = i * row.length;
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply ! I tried something similar but got an "infinite update loop"... Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Yeah thank you, but as I stated above, though your solution works, bcjohn's solution seems more simple and intuitive since it does not involve a method invocation between HTML...

Comment: Maybe you could change your answer without the method invocation ? or do you think invoking a function like this is a better approach ? (why?)

Comment: I prefer to keep logic in JS code, it becomes more user-friendly for developer instead of keeping the logic in HTML codes. And also the other solution will not work if you have different length of inner Arrays e.g. `allItems: [ ['a', 'b'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g']]`